# Proper way to push a view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIViewController that I wish to push onto the stack, however, when I call `[viewController release]` on it after I push it, any time I pop it off of the stack however, I get various errors pertaining to deallocated instances of the view controller. Here is an example of an implementation:

```
        RootViewController *rootViewcontroller = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" 
                                                                                          bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];
        [rootViewController release];
```

Comment: You're pushing a different view controller than the one you created.

Comment: What are the "various errors" that you are getting?

Comment: I've moved the discussion the be more error specific. The major problem is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376979/calayer-retaincount-sent-to-deallocated-instance

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you showed you create `rootViewController` but actually push `personsViewController`. Typo? Or did you paste the wrong code?

Comment: The code you show is perfectly fine. So it must be somewhere else. Like inside the `RootViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Your RootViewController instance is "rootViewcontroller" but you're pushing "rootViewController" (notice the 'C'?).